# Dynamic Links Working on Everything Except iOS Messenger on Physical Device (Flutter)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, unit-testing, firebase-dynamic-links

I am having an odd issue. I have spent quite some time getting dynamic links working on my flutter app and everything seems to be working great. I am able to create a link programmatically, pass in parameters, and handle the incoming links as necessary. They work great on an iOS and Android simulator, and even a physical iOS device EXCEPT for Apple's text messages. On the physical device, the links works fine for sharing to social media accounts, and if I copy/paste to a text message, it works. However, if you try to share directly to the messages, it only passes on the main url (https://example.com) and not the uriPrefix (https://example.page.link/params).

Link Generation:

```
class DynamicLinkService {
Future<Uri> createDynamicLink(String navPage, String id) async {
    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: 'https://example.page.link',
      link: Uri.parse('https://example.com/?navPage=$navPage&id=$id'),
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        packageName: 'com.example.example',
        minimumVersion: 1,
      ),
      iosParameters: IosParameters(
        bundleId: 'com.example.example',
        minimumVersion: '1',
        appStoreId: '12345678',
      ),
    );
    var dynamicUrl = await parameters.buildShortLink();
    final Uri shortUrl = dynamicUrl.shortUrl;
    return shortUrl;
}
```

On press link generation:

```
class _FeedPageWidgetState extends State<FeedPageWidget>
  final DynamicLinkService _dynamicLinkService = DynamicLinkService();

Align(
alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0),
child: FlutterFlowIconButton(                                 
 icon: Icon(),
    onPressed: () async {
    var uri = await _dynamicLinkService
    .createDynamicLink('param 1', 'param 2');
    await Share.share(uri.toString());
    print(uri.toString());
    },
  ),
),
```

The correct uri is printing the deeplink with the correct parameters, however, it is not sending it to the messages app but will for everything else. I am getting the error below on press.

```
[default] LaunchServices: store (null) or url (null) was nil: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=264, _LSFunction=-[_LSDReadClient getServerStoreWithCompletionHandler:]}
[default] Attempt to map database failed: permission was denied. This attempt will not be retried.
[db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=264, _LSFunction=-[_LSDReadClient getServerStoreWithCompletionHandler:]}
[default] -imageForImageDescriptor: can do IO please adopt -imageForDescriptor: for IO free drawing or -prepareImageForDescriptor: if IO is allowed. (This will become a fault soon.)
[default] LaunchServices: store (null) or url (null) was nil: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=264, _LSFunction=-[_LSDReadClient getServerStoreWithCompletionHandler:]}
[default] Attempt to map database failed: permission was denied. This attempt will not be retried.
[db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=264, _LSFunction=-[_LSDReadClient getServerStoreWithCompletionHandler:]}
[default] -imageForImageDescriptor: can do IO please adopt -imageForDescriptor: for IO free drawing or -prepareImageForDescriptor: if IO is allowed. (This will become a fault soon.)
[LayoutConstraints] Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a UICollectionReusableView that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, and will result in incorrect self-sizing. View: <_UIActivityContentFooterView: 0x15eba3f70; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (16 430.333; 343 52); layer = <CALayer: 0x283a61d80>>
<CATransformLayer: 0x283a1d580> - changing property backgroundColor in transform-only layer, will have no effect
[Process] 0x14b018618 - [pageProxyID=333, webPageID=334, PID=473] WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=6, domain=WebKitErrorDomain, code=102
[Process] 0x14b03d818 - [pageProxyID=336, webPageID=337, PID=473] WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=9, domain=WebKitErrorDomain, code=102
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x1041fb540 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=495, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x1041fb5a0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=496, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x1041fb600 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=497, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x1041fb660 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=473, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x1041fb6c0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID=497, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x1041fb720 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Suspended Assertion' for process with PID=497, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! I am curious if this has anything to do with the build not being 'production' or coming from the App Store?

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issues, but find a temporary fix.
Juste add **<Some_Prefix>** before the url string. But with that you will not have the Link Preview, when sharing.

```
await Share.share('Hello : ${uri.toString()}');
```

Or

```
await Share.share(' ${uri.toString()}'; // Just put an empty space before.
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I ended up having to do. The string prefix fixes the issue, but is kind of annoying.